# Converting a string into a double

Tags: c, string, pointers, double, constants

I am trying to convert a string (`const char* argv[]`) to a `double` precision floating point number:

```
int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    double numbers[argc - 1];
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i += 1) {
        /* -- Convert each argv into a double and put it in `number` */
    }
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Grrr! No. You want to convert a string, the beginning of which is pointed to, by a const char*, to double

Comment: @Maciej: Nah, every experienced C programmer knows a `const char*` is 99.9% a string.

Comment: @Kenny: Sure if it is the second argument of the `main` function.

Comment: Oh well, I just have a "being an ass day", I guess. I just couldn't resist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`sscanf` (Ref)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

```
sscanf(argv[i], "%lf", numbers+i);
```

or [`strtod` (Ref)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/)

```
numbers[i] = strtod(argv[i], NULL);
```

BTW,

```
for(i = 1; i < argc, i += 1) {
//-----------------^ should be a semicolon (;)
```

-->

Comment: `strtod` did the job. Thanks =D

Comment: Oh, and the `,` instead of a `;` was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `atof`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: No real reason to use atof anymore with the safer strtod

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtod](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtod.3.asp) which is defined in stdlib.h

Theoretically, it should be more efficient that the scanf-family of functions although I don't think it'll be measurable.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what format the `const char*`s might be in. Presuming they're text strings like "1.23", then `sscanf(argv[i], "%lf", &numbers[i-1])` ought to do the job.

Comment: I think I was referring to the difference between normal and scientific notation.