# string to decimal number in C

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string into a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892998/converting-a-string-into-a-double)

I need to convert `" 5.71"` to `5.71` in C.

I am reading in a string as a token, but need to store the value as a double.

Are there any functions that do this? And what print statement should I be using?

```
char *number = "5.71";
printf("%???", double);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: [converting a string into a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308536/converting-a-string-into-a-double), [Converting a string to double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601537/converting-a-string-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html).

> And what print statement should I be using?

The format specifier for `double` is `%lf`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
sscanf(number, "%f", &doubleVar);
```

That should be the 'standard' way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any functions that do this?

Yes, [strtod, strtof and strtold](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html) convert strings to `double`, `float` and `long double`, respectively. For example:

```
float f = strtof("2.718281829", NULL);
```

> And what print statement should I be using?

Euh, they're rather called **format specifiers.** Also they vary, depending on the exact type:

```
float f = 3.14;
double d = 3.14;
long double ld = 3.14;

printf("%f %lf %llf\n", f, d, ld);
```